# Href tag is not working when i am using notification div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a notification bar its work fine but the problem is that into my div href tag show the link but not click-able and I also use it into ul, li tag but its not working

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#notificationLink").click(function() {
            $("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);
            $("#notification_count").fadeOut("slow");
            return false;
        });

        //Document Click
        $(document).click(function() {
            //$("#notificationContainer").hide();
        });
        //Popup Click
        $("#notificationContainer").click(function() {
            return false
        });

    });
</script>
```

```css
<style>
body{background-color:#dedede;font-family:arial}
#nav{list-style:none;margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;}
#nav li {
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight:bold;
}


#notification_li{position:relative}
#notificationContainer {
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, .4);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
overflow: visible;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
margin-left: -170px;
width: 400px;

display: none;
}
#notificationContainer:before {

display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;

border: 10px solid black;
border-color: transparent transparent white;
margin-top: -20px;
margin-left: 188px;
}
#notificationTitle {

font-weight: bold;
padding: 8px;
font-size: 13px;
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 384px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
#notificationsBody {
padding: 33px 0px 0px 0px !important;
min-height:300px;
}
#notificationFooter {
background-color: #e9eaed;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 8px;
font-size: 12px;
border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
#notification_count {
padding: 3px 7px 3px 7px;
background: #cc0000;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: 77px;
border-radius: 9px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -11px;
font-size: 11px;
}
    #notificationul {
   list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -33px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  height: 332px;
  overflow-x: auto;
    }
        #notificationul li {
        height:82px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
        width:380px;
        }
    #liheader {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 370px;
    }
    #lidesc {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 360px;
  text-align: justify;
    }
    #notificationul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>sample</title>
    
</head>

<body >

<ul id="nav">
    <li>asasas</li>
    <li>asasas</li><li>asasas</li><li>asasas</li>
<li id="notification_li">
<span id="notification_count">3</span>
<a href="#" id="notificationLink">Notifications</a>
<div id="notificationContainer">
<div id="notificationTitle">Notifications</div>
<div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">
    <a href="abc.html" style="position:fixed">this is sample</a>
    
</div>
<div id="notificationFooter"><a href="#">See All</a></div>
</div>

</li>

</ul>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are u talking about *this is sample* link?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#notificationContainer").click(function()
{
//return false
});
```

When you add return false to a element then the default functionality of that element doesnt works it works similar to `e.preventDefault()`

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#notificationLink").click(function()
{
$("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);
$("#notification_count").fadeOut("slow");
return false;
});

//Document Click
$(document).click(function()
{
//$("#notificationContainer").hide();
});
//Popup Click
$("#notificationContainer").click(function()
{
//return false
});

});
</script>
```

```css
<style>
body{background-color:#dedede;font-family:arial}
#nav{list-style:none;margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;}
#nav li {
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight:bold;
}


#notification_li{position:relative}
#notificationContainer {
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, .4);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
overflow: visible;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
margin-left: -170px;
width: 400px;

display: none;
}
#notificationContainer:before {

display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;

border: 10px solid black;
border-color: transparent transparent white;
margin-top: -20px;
margin-left: 188px;
}
#notificationTitle {

font-weight: bold;
padding: 8px;
font-size: 13px;
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 384px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
#notificationsBody {
padding: 33px 0px 0px 0px !important;
min-height:300px;
}
#notificationFooter {
background-color: #e9eaed;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 8px;
font-size: 12px;
border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
#notification_count {
padding: 3px 7px 3px 7px;
background: #cc0000;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: 77px;
border-radius: 9px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -11px;
font-size: 11px;
}
    #notificationul {
   list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -33px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  height: 332px;
  overflow-x: auto;
    }
        #notificationul li {
        height:82px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
        width:380px;
        }
    #liheader {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 370px;
    }
    #lidesc {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 360px;
  text-align: justify;
    }
    #notificationul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>sample</title>
    
</head>

<body >

<ul id="nav">
    <li>asasas</li>
    <li>asasas</li><li>asasas</li><li>asasas</li>
<li id="notification_li">
<span id="notification_count">3</span>
<a href="#" id="notificationLink">Notifications</a>
<div id="notificationContainer">
<div id="notificationTitle">Notifications</div>
<div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">
    <a href="abc.html" style="position:fixed">this is sample</a>
    
</div>
<div id="notificationFooter"><a href="#">See All</a></div>
</div>

</li>

</ul>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You re preventing click by returning false here:

```
   $("#notificationContainer").click(function()
    {
    //return false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return `false`; it won't redirect to desired location!

**Remove `return false`**

### Function :

```
$("#notificationContainer").click(function()
{
    //return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent links, you can use `preventDefault` event.

```
$("#notificationContainer").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This event will work not only for links, also for submits and events that fires something by default.

Answer (score 0):

The return "false" for the click handler method is a way of preventing the default  browser behavior so if the hyperlink wants to  move into another location, this will be prevented. The new way of achieving this is by adding

> e.preventDefault();

and  to stop the event from bubbling up in the DOM Tree  if it is not consumed by the current event handler we add

> e.stopPropagation();